# Tuning priors/weights/costs to counteract class imbalance

Tags: machine-learning, classification, unbalanced-classes

I have a classification problem which consists of two classes. It has high class imbalance. There are around 85% data points for the negative class and only 15% for the positive class.

One option is upsampling but I would also like to try using priors/weights/costs of the classifiers.

How should the priors, weights or costs be chosen (or the range to search)?

Comment: Isn't it based on sample population you want to approximate?

Comment: [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he) is not a perfect duplicate but is worth a read to see why there probably is not anything to fix through selecting priors, weights, or costs.